# Can Bootstrap 4 Cards Have Tiled Background Images

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, background-image, tiles

I am trying to get a card to have a tiled background image. To get a single image background I use:

```
<div class="card img-fluid">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="images/backcard-brushedmetal.jpg">
  <div class="card-img-overlay">
    <div class="card-body text-justify">
      <h3 class="articleh3"><a href="#">xxxDescriptionxxx</a></h3>
      <p>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/xxxImagexxx.jpg" alt="xxxDescriptionxxx" height="100" width="80" style="margin-right: 10px;float: left" /></a>
        xxxSomeTextHerexxx
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that I use cards of different sizes and right now my image size is governing the size of my card; I guess I want it the other way round (the card to govern the size of the displayed background). So I wondered if it was possible to tile a background image so it just fills the background and then it shouldn't matter what size the card or image is.

For all I know, this may not even be possible and if not, that's fine, I'll look for another way to do something like :)

Anyway, thanks for any advice :)

James

Answer (score 0):

If the only purpose of using `img` element is as a background - use `background-image` [CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) which sets background image on an element.

Edit per comments: 
Obviously the `float` part cause some "problems" on the given markup, BUT there is something more out there... Can't figure myself why this not working - so i remove BS4 (added 2 examples):

```css
.card.img-fluid {
  background: url(http://www.rocksquad.co.uk/images/backcard-brushedmetal.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="card img-fluid">
  <div class="card-img-overlay">
    <div class="card-body text-justify">
      <h3 class="articleh3"><a href="#">xxxDescriptionxxx</a></h3>
      <p>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://www.rocksquad.co.uk/images/backcard-brushedmetal.jpg" alt="xxxDescriptionxxx" height="100" width="80" style="margin-right: 10px;" /></a>
        xxxSomeTextHerexxx<br>xxxSomeTextHerexxx
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="card img-fluid">
  <div class="card-img-overlay">
    <div class="card-body text-justify">
      <h3 class="articleh3"><a href="#">xxxDescriptionxxx</a></h3>
      <p>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://www.rocksquad.co.uk/images/backcard-brushedmetal.jpg" alt="xxxDescriptionxxx" height="100" width="80" style="margin-right: 10px;" /></a>
        xxxSomeTextHerexxx<br>xxxSomeTextHerexxx<br>        xxxSomeTextHerexxx<br>xxxSomeTextHerexxx<br>        xxxSomeTextHerexxx<br>xxxSomeTextHerexxx<br>        xxxSomeTextHerexxx<br>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This question need some "bootstrap 4 expert" to answer on - clearly this is not me (:

---

Old (not working) answer:

In your case, since you want the image would **cover** the element, you can do something like that:

```
<style>
.card.img-fluid {
  background: url(images/backcard-brushedmetal.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
</style>
<div class="card img-fluid">
  <div class="card-img-overlay">
    <div class="card-body text-justify">
      <h3 class="articleh3"><a href="#">xxxDescriptionxxx</a></h3>
      <p>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/xxxImagexxx.jpg" alt="xxxDescriptionxxx" height="100" width="80" style="margin-right: 10px;float: left" /></a>
        xxxSomeTextHerexxx
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, that didn't work or didn't seem to do anything; not sure why. I had to add "<img class="card-img-top" src="images/backcard-brushedmetal.jpg">" back in to even make it work and, when I change the size of the page (to mimic using a smaller screen), the background doesn't change, doesn't expand or extend. Adding the background image also seems to make the text "bleed" outside of the card. Thanks for trying anyway :)

Comment: Actually, the "bleeding" text (where text appears outside of the card) appears to be realted to <div class="card-img-overlay"> i.e. if I remove it, the card behaves properly but otherwise it doesn't.

Comment: @JamesRocks so i read the docs and it seems that you are trying to do this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#image-overlays . So (a) you need to use the proper classes and (b) Check this note: Turn an image into a card background and overlay your card’s text. Depending on the image, you may or may not need additional styles or utilities. (c) upload your image and i'll try to help.

Comment: Um, how do I upload the image I am using? Does this link help? http://www.rocksquad.co.uk/images/backcard-brushedmetal.jpg. James

Comment: @JamesRocks sorry but i didn't manage to get this to work with BS4. I add example without it and some notes. Hope you'll get your BS4 answer (:

Comment: No worries. Thank you for trying anyway :)